# How to get order username and provisionDate for all SoftLayer machines using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Using Ruby I'm making a call like:

```
client = SoftLayer::Client.new(:username => user, :api_key => api_key, :timeout => 999999)
client['Account'].object_mask("mask[id, hostname, fullyQualifiedDomainName, provisionDate, datacenter[name], billingItem[recurringFee, associatedChildren[recurringFee], orderItem[description, order[userRecord[username], id]]], tagReferences[tagId, tag[name]], primaryIpAddress, primaryBackendIpAddress]").getHardware
```

But only some machines return a provisionDate and only some return orderItem information.  How can I consistently get this information for each machine?  What would cause one machine to return this data and another machine to not?

Example output:

```
{"fullyQualifiedDomainName"=>"<removed_by_me>",
 "hostname"=>"<removed_by_me>",
 "id"=>167719,
 "provisionDate"=>"",
 "primaryBackendIpAddress"=>"<removed_by_me>",
 "primaryIpAddress"=>"<removed_by_me>",
 "billingItem"=>
  {"recurringFee"=>"506.78",
   "associatedChildren"=>
    [<removed_by_me>]},
 "datacenter"=>{"name"=>"dal09"},
  "tagReferences"=>
  [{"tagId"=>139415, "tag"=>{"name"=>"<removed_by_me>"}},
   {"tagId"=>139417, "tag"=>{"name"=>"<removed_by_me>"}},
   {"tagId"=>140549, "tag"=>{"name"=>"<removed_by_me>"}}]}
```

To be clear, most machines return this data so I'm trying to understand why some do not.

Comment: The provisionDate is filled once the provisioning proces has been ended. So the machines which do not have the provisión date are still in provisioning. Inregard the order ítem that is weird, please review if those machines are in provisioning or in cancelación proccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the following provisioning steps, below is a little flow to consider:

```
1.  Order a Server

Result: 
* An orderId is assigned to the server
* The createDate has a new value
* activeTransaction value is =  Null
* provisionDate value is = Null

2.  The order is approved

Result: 
* activeTransaction value is <> Null
* provisionDate value = Null

3.  Server  is already provisioned

Result:
* activeTransaction value is = Null
* provisionDate value has a New value
* billingItem property has a new value
```

To see if your machines have still `”activeTransaction”`, please execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/[server_id]/getActiveTransaction
Method: GET
```

Now, after reviewing your example response, this server had some problems when completing the provisioning; for that reason this step was completed manually but the `provisionDate` was not set for any reason(please open a ticket if you want that the provisionDate can be set) . This is a special case. I can see that another server has a similar behavior. But the other servers that don’t have `provisionDate`, have still `”activeTransaction<>null”` (it means that these server are not provisioned yet).

**EDIT:**

Other property can help you to know that your machine has been already provisioned although other kind of transaction is being executed, is `“hardwareStatus”`, it should have “ACTIVE” value.

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware?objectMask=mask[id, hostname, fullyQualifiedDomainName, provisionDate,hardwareStatus]
Method: GET
```

The response should be something like this:

```
{
"fullyQualifiedDomainName": "myhostname.softlayer.com"
"hostname": " myhostname"
"id": 1234567
"provisionDate": "2015-06-29T00:21:39-05:00"
"hardwareStatus": {
"id": 5
"status": "ACTIVE"
}
```

Comment: Thanks mcruz.  This is actually a lot of useful information.  One question, can the activeTransaction field ever be NOT equal to null after the machine is provisioned?  I'm wondering if there are other cases where transactions occur.  If there are, do you have another field you recommend using that is a good indicator a machine is provisioned (a reliable field), maybe primaryBackendIpAddress?

Comment: Other property can help you to know that your machine has been already provisioned although other kind of transaction is been executed, is `“hardwareStatus”`, it should have “ACTIVE” value. I added some info in **EDIT** section of the answer.