# Retrieving user metadata about a provisioned SoftLayer server comes back null

Tags: ruby, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to retrieve the user meta information for each machine consistently but what I'm finding is *most* of my machines are missing this data.  I'd like to understand better what is required for this user data to be there.  I'm curious if a server can be requested and provisioned without requiring user information (e.g. an API call to order a server and no user data is given).  Or whether I am missing something in how I retrieve this information.  Here is the basic ruby program I'm running:

```
user = ###
api_key = ###

client = SoftLayer::Client.new(:username => user, :api_key => api_key, :timeout => 999999)

list_of_virtual_machines = client['Account'].result_limit(i*50,50).object_mask("mask[id, billingItem[recurringFee, associatedChildren[recurringFee], orderItem[description, order[userRecord[username], id]]], userData]").getVirtualGuests
for x in 0..list_of_virtual_machines.length - 1
  pp list_of_virtual_machines[i]['userData']
  if list_of_virtual_machines[i]['billingItem'] && list_of_virtual_machines[i]['billingItem']['orderItem'] && list_of_virtual_machines[i]['billingItem']['orderItem']['order'] && list_of_virtual_machines[i]['billingItem']['orderItem']['order']['userRecord']
    pp list_of_virtual_machines[i]['billingItem']['orderItem']['order']['userRecord']
  end
end
```

My prints are consistently showing null.  This question is related to a similar question I asked not too long ago (but the focus of that question moved towards the provisionDate):
[How to get order username and provisionDate for all SoftLayer machines using Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164444/how-to-get-order-username-and-provisiondate-for-all-softlayer-machines-using-rub)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are missing that data because you did not added.

you can create the user data at moment to order a new server or VSI, you just have to send the data in your order request either using the **createObject** method or the **placeOrder** method. see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject

e.g.

```
{ 
    "userData": [ 
        { 
            "value": "someValue" 
        } 
    ] 
}
```

or you can set it after the server has been provisioned using these methods

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/setUserMetadata
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/setUserMetadata

Basically the usermetadata are useful if you are going to use a post install script. The usermetadata value is not required to order a new server

take a look this article for examples:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/jarteche/getting-started-user-data-and-post-provisioning-scripts